# create database before start programming by asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: sql-server, web, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to learn `MVC 5` and I have problem to connect to my database (`SQL Server`) I searched and find some solution but didn't work for me. So I want to know I have to create a database, a table and diagrams first, before I start to programming Asp.Net MVC 5 web application?

Comment: PS: I know how Entity Framwork works out but it's not my answer. Thanks everybody.

Comment: If you don't post any code, how you expect us to guess the issue and provide and working solution? If you are learning about MVC and Database, yes you need to learn some basics of the database.

Comment: Or if not code, at the least post the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio and create a database and a user for your application.

You then add the correct connection string an put it in your `web.config`. This depends heavily on your database setup. Here is a basic example (you need to at lease fill in *Servername*, *UserId* and *Password*):

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

More options can be found in the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ok. How should I do that? The generate connection string part, I mean

Comment: SSMS doesn't give you the connection string easily (though it should). It's much easier to get from Visual Studio in the Server Explorer (not the SQL Server Object Explorer). *Ctrl+Alt+S*. Assuming the database was actually created, you should see it under SQL Server>(localdb)\...>Databases. Right click on the database and click properties. Under properties, you will see Connection String under the General section.

Answer (score 0):

If you use one of the CRUD templates, the database will be created through Entity Framework for you locally. If it's not connecting to the generated database, you can try the following code in the Application_Start method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<schoolcontext>());
    using (var context = new SchoolContext())
    {
        context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
    }
}
```